# angularjs $valid on dates reports incorrectly in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date, firefox

I have noticed an issue with form validation on dates within firefox, that I would greatly appreciate any advice or a usable work-around for.

**Date Validation Problem**

I am using angularjs v1.3.11, and the issue i'm experiencing is actually with the bootstrap datepicker, however it is the same issue for a standard input type="date" field.

If I put an invalid leap day e.g. *29/02/2013* (en-GB date - DD/MM/YYYY) into a text field using bootstrap datepicker or an input type="date" field $valid on that form field reports as invalid on ALL browser accept for firefox.  I really want it to report as invalid on every browser!

It appears to invalidate a date, if I for example put complete garbage into the field such as entering a date without a month so *29/2013* would quite rightly report as invalid in all browsers I've tested.  It's almost as if angular is running a special regex for firefox that doesn't care about the validity of a date other than that it has 3 sets of numbers in it.

**Viewing this date issue on the angular website**

If you select the following link https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D you will be taken to angulars own write up of input[date].

Follow the link in **firefox** - scrolling to the bottom of the page to the example they've put on the screen and type in an invalid date such as 29th February 2013 (It seems to need ISO date format for firefox on this site) and you will see it report the date youv'e entered as **valid**, even though there is no 29th February in 2013 as it was not a leap year.

If you perform the same test in **chrome** for example, then you will see it report the date as **INVALID** - which is what I wish to happen.

**How to resolve this?**
Thankyou if you've managed to read this far! I realise that this may be an issue with how a particular browser deals with dates, although i've searched far and wide and haven't found any listed bugs for this in either firefox or angular.

What i'm really hoping here, is that someone may know a work-around, for example a way of intercepting the call that determines $valid on an input field, so that I can run my own regex or something like that.  If anyone know's why this is so strange in firefox i'd love to know that too!

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer :)

Lindsay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more sophisticated date logic to determine if a date is valid.  I suggest using a third party library like moment.js or date.js to perform the date validation logic.

Try the demo link at the bottom of the accepted answer for the following SO question:

[Simple angularjs date input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565719/simple-angularjs-date-input/24567100#24567100)

Enter 2013-02-29, it will correctly identify the date is invalid.

Tested on Firefox, IE, and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution makes sense.  I appear to be using the wrong version of Moment, because it's accepting really random things as a date such as a single digit, but that's another issue that apparently is in an older version of moment! I'm not sure how i've managed to download such an old version, but i'll fix that and i'm sure everything would be fine :)